# How to check if value is v:null?

Tags: vimscript

What is the proper way to check if a particular variable is null? I use `v:null` as a special value to indicate something in a custom function's return value.

I have tried:

```
let l:v = v:null
echom l:v == v:null   " Works fine
let l:v = {'file': "something"}
echom l:v == v:null   " E735: Can only compare Dictionary with Dictionary
```

Note for searchers: null is sometimes called None, empty or nil.

Comment: I would try `is` instead of `==` (can't test rn).

Comment: Correct, thank you. It would be great to specify in the answer also how to test 'is not' - it is a bit counterintuitive `echom !(l:v is v:null)`

Comment: Actually, there's also `isnot`. I'm writing an answer.

Comment: I almost always write `is#` even when it's not needed, and almost never write `==`. Then I have less thinking to do, _and_ I don't get weird conversions I don't want (strings and numbers). This is likely because Martin persuaded me with the article linked in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator will check for *value*.

You need to check *identity*. This is done with the `is` (and `isnot`) operator. Use `is#` to match the case, `is?` to ignore it.

For example:

```
if l:v is v:null
  echom "Null"
endif
if l:v isnot v:null
  echom "Not null"
endif
```

There is a list of operators at `:h expr4`. You can use e.g `:h expr-==` as well, or just `:h ==`.

I also recommend reading [Effective VimScript](https://www.arp242.net/effective-vimscript.html) from [Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/martin-tournoij).